# Records count by field name. Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server

The task is, to calculate number of records for each column in the table where value is ''.

As an example, TABLE MARA has column 'LVORM' so my query will look like this:

```
select count(*) from MARA where LVORM = ''
```

what I have done is created the cursor script:

```
declare @TABLE_NAME varchar(50), @COLUMN_NAME varchar(50), @NOBLANKS INT, @q  nvarchar(max);

DECLARE cur_headers CURSOR
STATIC FOR SELECT top 50 TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'MARA' and COLUMN_NAME = 'LVORM'
OPEN cur_headers
IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0
 BEGIN 
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_headers INTO @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME
 WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
 BEGIN
    set @NOBLANKS = 0;
    select  @q = 'select @NOBLANKS = count(*) from MARA where ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' = '''' ';
    exec(@q)
    select @NOBLANKS;
    select @q;
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_headers INTO @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME
 END
END
CLOSE cur_headers
DEALLOCATE cur_headers
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

For some reason I'm not getting numbers of records back in variable `@NOBLANKS`
`@q` returns the right query

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable:

```
select  @q = 'select @NOBLANKS = count(*) from MARA where ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' = '''' ';
exec(@q)
```

=>

```
EXEC sp_executesql 
     N'select @NOBLANKS = count(*) from MARA where ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' = '''' ',
     N'@NOBLANKS INT OUT',
     @NOBLANKS OUT;
```

---

```
DECLARE cur_headers CURSOR STATIC FOR 
SELECT top 50 TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MARA';
  --AND COLUMN_NAME = 'LVORM';
  -- here the COLUMN_NAME is defaulted to `LVORM` so it should be removed
```

Semicolons are optional, but it is good to end each statement with them. After all we write code for humans.